# PHP Social Network Analysis Library

Tags: php, social-networking, analytics

Does anybody know of any PHP social network analysis libraries?  I've found NetworkX for Python, but nothing for PHP.  Again, not something for drawing, but actual mathematical analysis of already-drawn networks.

Comment: If you don't find anything you could port the NetworkX library from Python to PHP (or just write your web application in python :D)

Comment: This question is incredibly vague, I feel. Please can you explain exactly what type of analysis you wish to perform with data from which social networks? Facebook, Twitter et al. generally provide APIs for extracting raw data, so I sure it will be possible, but some of them are something of a moving target and hard to wrap in a library that will work for more than a week, no names mentioned <cough>facebook<cough>. Do you want a library that will retrieve and process the data for you, or just one you throw data into after you retrieved it yourself? What data? What result would you want from it?

Comment: Sorry, for clarification: I mean a 'social network' in the more scientific sense (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_network). The data would be supplied from a database. I want to find things like degree centrality, betweenness centrality, closeness centrality, etc., based on the connections defined in the database. I already have code for building the network.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Java to do the analysis.

1. Java for analyzing the social network. (e.g. [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/))
2. Export the result to PHP like reading the results from Java using PHP.

Since I saw the comments that you already built the network, why not using Java/ Python to read your network. Based on the analysis from Python (i.e. write the result on disk/memory), you can still reuse the result on PHP, right?

Currently, I didn't see any library for social network analysis using PHP. You know, it would be much more computational intensive using PHP to do such mathematical things. Most of the guys do this in the back-end, like PHP "call/execute" some Java programs to run the results.

PHP will then read the results and shows to the user's browser.